# Как передать список, состоящий из '{\$_POST['Name']}' в VALUES?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Чтение руководства и поиск в интернете не помогают мне, видимо потому что плохо формулирую вопрос. Поэтому обращаюсь к вам с развёрнутым вопросом, уважаемые Stackoverflow'чане.

Я пытаюсь занести в бд информацию при помощи '{$_POST['Name']}', перед этим сгенерировав список, который занесен в переменную $list = '{$_POST['Name']}', '{$_POST['Surname']}' (Список со значениями 'Name', 'Surname' берётся из БД - это имена таблиц)

$list = '{$_POST['Name']}', '{$_POST['Surname']}' невозможно создать без добавления обратного слэша, поэтому это выглядит так

$list = '{\$_POST['Name']}', '{\$_POST['Surname']}'

Соответственно:

VALUES ($list) выдаёт ошибку. Пробовал различные преобразования - не помогает, поэтому ПАМАГИТИ. Возможно это основы основ, но мне, к сожалению, не удаётся найти решение.

Comment: Если сделать echo '$list' и из браузера скопировать в VALUES всё работает, поэтому делаю вывод, что проблема только в обратном слэше

Comment: \\ пробывали?..

Comment: пробовал - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Comment: По сути можно сгенерировать один раз моим способом и вставить в Values, но планируется менять название столбцов, поэтому придётся генерировать постоянно. Хотелось бы узнать, какие ВООБЩЕ есть варианты реализации задачи - вставить во все  имеющиеся столбцы значения, ну и решение именно ДАННОЙ задачи интересует не меньше. Уже писал функции, как только не пытался обмануть не получается совсем.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.list.php

Comment: Очень близко... Но даже после прочтения не совсем понятен путь решения, т.е. возникает вопрос - как в этот список внести то количество переменных, которое необходимо (а если я его не знаю). Большая просьба немного конкретизировать, или лучше показать как это делается. В любом случае СПАСИБО.